# What is new in the fifth edition of Dvoretsky's Endgame Manual?

Tags: endgame, books

It seems the only change between the fourth and fifth edition (after the author's passing) was a change in color. This surely can't be enough for a new edition, so I wonder what changes to the content were made?

> German grandmaster Karsten Müller, widely recognized as one of the best endgame theoreticians in the world today, has carefully updated the fifth edition with the help of American grandmaster Alex Fishbein. The incredible instructional value of the exercises has been preserved, and the blue text used in the first four editions has been replaced with text with a light grey background.

Answer (score 5):

1. The fifth edition (DEM5) has 440 pages, 16 more than the fourth edition. The book has been completely reformatted, and the diagrams have all been re-set.
2. There is a new foreword by former world champion Vladimir Kramnik and a new introduction by Karsten Müller.
3. The revision has been done by German GM Karsten Müller. With the passing of Mark Dvoretsky, Karsten has been generally recognized as the premier endgame analyst and theoretician in the world today.
   American GM Alex Fishbein assisted Karsten.
4. There have been new developments in several areas of theory (e.g., Bishop Endgames), and these were added.
5. Karsten and Alex have gone through the existing text of DEM4 very carefully, making minor changes and corrections throughout. New diagrams have been added, some have been removed. The complex indexing systems put in place by Dvoretsky have been modified accordingly.
6. The blue text in previous editions has been replaced by normal text highlighted with a light gray background.

Comment: Thank you very much for the list! Only point 4 seems to concern "actual content". Do you happen to know in which areas developments have been added?

Comment: @Anna  I'm using 3rd edition so no personal experience.  I believe everything was reviewed with a 7-man tablebase but not sure about that.